# Accessing VS complete solution in roslyn

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

How can we access the complete visual studio solution from code analyzer in `Roslyn`?

I have been trying semantic analysis without much help.

```
var sol = ((Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.WorkspaceAnalyzerOptions)context.Options)
    .Workspace.CurrentSolution;
```

This is what I came up with using intellisense but this always gives a **null** value.

Comment: What does `Workspace` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can't.  Analyzers run as part of commandline builds in csc and vbc, which have no notion of Workspaces or Solutions.

We are considering adding a VS specific analyzer API that would allow access to the `Solution`, but for Roslyn's 1.0 release, there is no supported way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment `WorkspaceAnalyzerOptions` is `internal sealed`. One can use `context.Options` with `reflection`. **Hacky**, but working.

```
Solution solution =
    ((HostWorkspaceServices)context
    .Options
    .GetType()
    .GetRuntimeProperty("Services")
    .GetValue(context.Options))
    .Workspace
    .CurrentSolution;
```

**Note**, along with it the compiler gives a warning:

> RS1022 Change diagnostic analyzer type to remove all direct accesses to type(s) 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.HostWorkspaceServices, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace'